# What is the format for the JSON passed into an IBM ODM REST service call?

Tags: json, rest, odm

I have an IBM ODM server installed with a ruleset on it. I've tested the ruleset using native tools.

Now I want to call a rule using JSON and the REST API available in ODM.

I know the REST URL, which looks something like this:

http://server:port/DecisionService/rest/MyRule/1.0/MyRuleset/1.0

What I need to know, preferably by example, the basic structure of the JSON I need to send to that URL when when I POST to it. I know that some of the JSON will be specific to the parameters my rule accepts, but I think I can figure that out given an example "wrapper".

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The RES console provides some features to help. From the Explorer tab, use the Navigator pane to select your ruleset and expose it in the Ruleset View pane. Select "Retrieve HTDS Description File", which should bring up a dialog box. Select REST as the "Service protocol type", then select the "Format" you are interested in, such as "OpenAPI - JSON". Finally, select View or Download to see the service specification. 
By selecting Test, you can view a sample request, but it includes only the portion specific to your operations, not the service-level wrapper info.